# How to add objects into Redux reducers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, react-redux

I'm using Redux with Next JS, and i'm trying to add array of objects to it. in my app i have a form with multiple inputs. to create this multiple input i've created an input form of 10.

```
{homeAmeneties.map((home) => {
    <div className="h-8 flex justify-end  rounded-md pr-10">
                    <input
                      type="number"
                      onInput={(event) =>
                        (event.target.value = event.target.value.slice(
                          0,
                          event.target.maxLength
                        ))
                      }
                      maxLength="3"
                      onChange={(e) => updateVal(e, home.name)}
                      className="border-[1px] w-1/2  border-black rounded-md h-full focus:outline-none px-2"
                    />
                  </div>
})}
```

each of the values from the input is added to an array. but i wanted to add it into redux array. in my redux reducer i've created

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  arr: []
}

export const arrSlice = createSlice({
  name: "arrS",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setArr: (state, action) => {
      state.arr = [...state.arr, action.payload];
    }
  }
});

//...rest here
```

when i run this it throws `TypeError: action.payload is not iterable`, i've tried to add it just by passing as `state.arr = action.payload;` and it doesn't store the input as array of objects, just simple object.

How can i add and make tweeks like i can do it in simple useState?

the code below is what i did with regular `useState()`

```
 const [amen, setAmen] = useState([]);

const updateVal = (e, type) => {
    setAmen((prevAmen) => {
      const newAmen = [...prevAmen]; // create a copy of the current state
      const index = newAmen.findIndex((item) => item.name === type); // find the index of the object with the matching name
      if (e.target.value === "") {
        if (index !== -1) {
          newAmen.splice(index, 1);
        }
      } else {
        if (index !== -1) {
          newAmen[index] = { name: type, val: e.target.value }; // update the object at that index
        } else {
          newAmen.push({ name: type, val: e.target.value }); // add a new object to the array
        }
      }
      return newAmen;
    });
    dispatch(setRooms(...amen));
    console.log(rooms);
  };
```

Comment: console.log "action.payload" in this code to see what you are receiving in payload

setArr: (state, action) => {
      state.arr = [...state.arr, action.payload];
    }

Comment: @SahilArdeshna it returns an object. `{name: 'Bedroom', val: '12'}` but my data i used on input was not this. `{name: 'item1', val: '12'},{name: 'item2', val: '232'},{name: 'item3', val: '434'}` this should be on the value

Comment: Check if you are dispatching an array and if it is an array then you have to update this as well `state.arr = [...state.arr, ...action.payload];`

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this if anyone wants a solution. before that let me explain what it does.

i have an array of objects that's coming from an input fields. and when these fields value changes it trigger the Redux dispatch. if the array exists it updates that array if not , well it creates new array.

the data i have is something like below

```
[
  {name: "name1" , val: 27},
  {name: "name2" , val: 26},
  {name: "name3" , val: 25},
  {name: "name4" , val: 24},
  {name: "name5" , val: 23},
  {name: "name6" , val: 22},
]
```

and when input `onChange()` triggers, it dispatch the data to redux. `onChange={(e) => handleChange(name, e.target.value)}`

```
const handleChange = (name, val) =>{
  const obj = { name: name, val: val };
  dispatch(setUser(obj))
}
```

and in the reducer

```
setUser: (state, action) => {
      const newState = [...state.users];
      const type = action.payload;

      const index = newState.findIndex((item) => item.name === type.name);

      if (type.val === "") {
        if (index !== -1) {
          newState.splice(index, 1);
        }
      } else {
        if (index !== -1) {
          newState[index] = { name: type.name, val: type.val };
        } else {
          newState.push({ name: type.name, val: type.val });
        }
      }

      state.users = [...newState];
      console.log(state.users);
    },
```

hopefully this helps someone.